# Invalid constant for day-time interval: org.apache.flink.table.api.ApiExpression

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have following simple code that performs processing time based tumble window, with table api, but an exception throws when I run it. How can I resolve this?

The Stock case class is defined as follows:

`case class Stock(id: String, trade_date: Timestamp, price: Double)`

The application code is:

```
package org.example.sqlcookbook

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.api.{AnyWithOperations, FieldExpression, Tumble, lit}
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala._
import org.apache.flink.types.Row
import org.example.sources.StockSource


    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    val ds = env.addSource(new StockSource(emitInterval = 1500, print = false))
    val tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    val table = tenv.fromDataStream(ds, $"id", $"trade_date", $"price", $"pt".proctime())
    val result = table.window(Tumble.over(lit(4).second()).on($"pt").as("w"))
      .groupBy($"id", $"w")
      .select(
        $"id",
        $"w".start().as("w_start"),
        $"w".`end`().as("w_end"),
        $"price".sum().as("sum_price")
      )

    result.toAppendStream[Row].print()
    env.execute()
```

The StockSource is:

```
package org.example.sources

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction.SourceContext
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.{RichSourceFunction, SourceFunction}
import org.example.model.Stock
import  org.example.utils.Implicits._
import scala.util.Try

class StockSource(emitInterval: Int = 0, print: Boolean = false) extends RichSourceFunction[Stock] {
  val fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  val running = true

  override def run(sc: SourceContext[Stock]): Unit = {
    //Stock Collection
    Stock.stocks.foreach {
      stock =>
        sc.collect(stock)

        if (print) {
          System.out.println("Source-" + stock.trade_date.to_str + "-" + stock.price)
        }

        if (emitInterval > 0) {
          Thread.sleep(emitInterval)
        }
    }
    //Keep Running
    while (true) {
      Try {
        Thread.sleep(Long.MaxValue)
      }
    }

  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = {
  }
}
```

The Stock object is:

```
object Stock {

  val stocks = Seq(
    Stock("id1", "2020-09-16 20:50:15".ts, 1),
    Stock("id1", "2020-09-16 20:50:12".ts, 2),
    Stock("id1", "2020-09-16 20:50:11".ts, 3),
    Stock("id1", "2020-09-16 20:50:18".ts, 4),
    Stock("id1", "2020-09-16 20:50:13".ts, 5),
    Stock("id1", "2020-09-16 20:50:20".ts, 6),
    Stock("id1", "2020-09-16 20:50:14".ts, 7),
    Stock("id1", "2020-09-16 20:50:22".ts, 8),
    Stock("id1", "2020-09-16 20:50:40".ts, 9)
  )


}
```

The exception message is:

```
Invalid constant for day-time interval: org.apache.flink.table.api.ApiExpression@731692
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Invalid constant for day-time interval: org.apache.flink.table.api.ApiExpression@731692
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.ApiExpressionUtils.lambda$toMilliInterval$6(ApiExpressionUtils.java:315)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.apache.flink.table.expressions.ApiExpressionUtils.toMilliInterval(ApiExpressionUtils.java:315)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.BaseExpressions.second(BaseExpressions.java:1193)
    at org.example.sqlcookbook.T006_GroupByProcessWindow$$anonfun$2.apply(T006_GroupByProcessWindow.scala:42)
    at org.example.sqlcookbook.T006_GroupByProcessWindow$$anonfun$2.apply(T006_GroupByProcessWindow.scala:36)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$$anon$1.apply(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:189)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite$class.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite.withFixture(AnyFunSuite.scala:1562)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:186)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:199)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:199)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$class.runTest(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:199)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite.runTest(AnyFunSuite.scala:1562)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:232)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:232)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:475)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$class.runTests(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:232)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite.runTests(AnyFunSuite.scala:1562)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1112)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite.org$scalatest$funsuite$AnyFunSuiteLike$$super$run(AnyFunSuite.scala:1562)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:236)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:236)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:535)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuiteLike$class.run(AnyFunSuiteLike.scala:236)
    at org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite.run(AnyFunSuite.scala:1562)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1320)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1314)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1314)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:972)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:971)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1480)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:971)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:798)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2or3(ScalaTestRunner.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:27)
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Could you share the code of `org.example.sources.StockSource` ?

Comment: Hi @Svend. I have add the code, please help take a look, thanks!

Comment: Please help take a look, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'm trying to run the code to understand the error, though I'm still unable to run it: can you provide the `Stock` and `Stocks` classes? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Svend. I have add the code `Stock` case class and object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is really not clear, although what's going on is a clash between the java syntax and the scala syntax for the tumbling window expression.

This is the java syntax for a tumbling window, and doesn't seem to be accepted by the scala API:

```
// this does not work in scala:
//  val result = table.window(Tumble.over(lit(4).second()).on($"pt").as("w"))
```

Somehow when called from scala the "4" seems to end up wrapped one time too many and fails to be converted into the "4 seconds" duration,

This scala syntax solves it:

```
import org.apache.flink.table.api._

...
// this works in scala:
table.window(Tumble.over(4.second()).on($"pt").as("w"))
```

In both cases it's the same `second()` function that gets called, although in the second case its argument is having the expected type.

Note that you can also have fun with this kind of syntax:

```
val result = table.window(Tumble over 4.second on $"pt" as "w")
```

Comment: Thanks @svend for the effort investigating the problem and find the root cause. It works for me now, thanks a lot!